# How to divide items in the inventory?

Tags: xbox-360, deus-ex-human-revolution

Sometimes you have multiple items stacked on the inventory, for example four energy bars, and you want throw only one in your apartment.

It is possible on the xbox version to split stacked items in your inventory? I already know you can sell the items individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly on the PC version I have not found a way to split an item stack in your inventory - other than selling individual items as you identified, or consuming items in some other way (eg eating an energy bar, or reloading a weapon to 'eat up' some of an ammo stack.)

I can't speak directly for the Xbox 360 version but I would be surprised if that functionality had been introduced on the console and not on the PC.

For what it's worth (and I know this doesn't directly answer your question) in my personal experience it's not a problem that I've encountered; inventory *space* is the key challenge, and the number of items in a stack doesn't affect this (unless the stack is at its maximum size and any further items picked up will need a new stack.) I find I have more energy bars than I can find time to use at any rate.

I should add that this is based on Deus Ex: Human Revolution: Director's Cut, build 2.0.0.0, in case they patch it in at a later date.